# Codename one:Windows build size is very large

Tags: codenameone

Windows build size is very large as compare to android and IOS.

What is the solution for reduced windows build size in codename one?

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit inherent in the platform it produces universal fat binaries that include x64 & ARM code within

Comment: Is there any way to reduces windows build size and other build size as well ?

Comment: Windows builds include 3 binaries bundled: ARM, x86, and x64.  You can reduce build size by only building for a single architecture.  In Codename One Settings > Windows, select "Custom Build", and it will let you explicitly select the platforms you want to build for.